# Matlab GUI gives an internal error when trying to maximize

Tags: matlab, user-interface, runtime-error

I have written a programmatic GUI, which uses a timer function to plot images and at same time plot the graphs, dynamically, as the image changes. So it looks a like video is being played, and the corresponding graph is getting plotted as the video progresses.

I am getting this internal error, whenever I'm trying to maximize the GUI. I'm attaching the scrrenshot of the error. Behind the error you can see the GUI itself.

[image]

I have no clue as to why this is happening. Please help!

Here is what it shows when I click on details :

```
MATLAB crash file:C:\Users\VARDHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.252-1:


------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Fri Dec 26 16:37:22 2014
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : windows-1252
  MATLAB Architecture: win64
  MATLAB Root        : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a
  MATLAB Version     : 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 7
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 111 Model 19 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Fault Count: 1


    Abnormal termination:
    Segmentation violation

    Register State (from fault):
      RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 0000000103e94330
      RCX = 0065006c00200065  RDX = 000000002b2e46e8
      RSP = 0000000004025a78  RBP = 000000002b2e4690
      RSI = 000000002b2e4690  RDI = 0000000004025ba8

       R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 000011e901ca0084
      R10 = 000000002acacaa0  R11 = 0000000004025ab0
      R12 = 0000000000000000  R13 = 0000000004025ba8
      R14 = 000000010380bdd4  R15 = 000000010380bb10

      RIP = 0000000073d156d0  EFL = 00010206

       CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

    Stack Trace (from fault):
    [  0] 0x0000000073d156d0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwgui.dll+00349904 NStrings::getNumStrings+00000000
    [  1] 0x00000000053855f1    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+02250225 GetObjectTextBounds+00002001
    [  2] 0x00000000052f0a16    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+01640982 getARDonAxis+00001094
    [  3] 0x00000000052f6c7d    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+01666173 getARDonAxis+00026285
    [  4] 0x00000000052f6eaa    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+01666730 getARDonAxis+00026842
    [  5] 0x00000000052f822b    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+01671723 getARDonAxis+00031835
    [  6] 0x00000000052d9183    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+01544579 get_axis_position+00000323
    [  7] 0x00000000053e3543    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+02635075 hgConvertUDInterfaceToHandle+00008371
    [  8] 0x0000000074f778ea   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd.dll+00227562 UDInterface::getE+00000362
    [  9] 0x00000000053e50d3    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+02642131 hgConvertUDInterfaceToHandle+00015427
    [ 10] 0x00000000053ba8ee    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+02468078 HGConversionUtils::convertKey+00000126
    [ 11] 0x00000000053dad75    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+02600309 addPropertiesToPropertyMap+00008245
    [ 12] 0x00000000053c21df    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+02499039 ggo_includeRenderer+00003151
    [ 13] 0x00000000053d6924    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+02582820 hgGet+00001524
    [ 14] 0x0000000074b52680 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hgbuiltins.dll+00140928 MLTerminate_hgbuiltins+00136720
    [ 15] 0x0000000074e8cf7f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00053119 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000975
    [ 16] 0x0000000074e8cd8f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052623 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000479
    [ 17] 0x00000000046b6d48 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00683336 inDestroyWS+00240776
    [ 18] 0x00000000046b91ff C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00692735 inDestroyWS+00250175
    [ 19] 0x00000000046d021f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00786975 inDestroyWS+00344415
    [ 20] 0x00000000046d0370 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00787312 inDestroyWS+00344752
    [ 21] 0x00000000046af1dd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00651741 inDestroyWS+00209181
    [ 22] 0x00000000046b0bd0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00658384 inDestroyWS+00215824
    [ 23] 0x000000000469cf79 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00577401 inDestroyWS+00134841
    [ 24] 0x0000000074e8c64f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00050767 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000623
    [ 25] 0x0000000074e8ced2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00052946 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000802
    [ 26] 0x0000000074ea022f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00131631 mdSearch::mdSearch+00000367
    [ 27] 0x0000000074e8e71b C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00059163 mdMxarrayFunctionHandle::isHiddenFunctionBinding+00000491
    [ 28] 0x0000000075a66194 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmx.dll+00287124 mxFevalFunctionHandle+00000036
    [ 29] 0x000000000463da0e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00186894 inFullFevalFcn+00000142
    [ 30] 0x0000000073ccb878 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwgui.dll+00047224 MCallback::_execute+00000200
    [ 31] 0x0000000073ccbab8 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwgui.dll+00047800 MCallback::execute+00000408
    [ 32] 0x0000000005c17d4f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd_mi.dll+00097615 judiConstructListener+00057855
    [ 33] 0x0000000074f7ae38   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd.dll+00241208 uddSetListenerRecursionWarning+00000680
    [ 34] 0x0000000074f7b48c   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd.dll+00242828 UDListenerManagerHost::notifyEvent+00000076
    [ 35] 0x0000000074f738dd   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd.dll+00211165 UDEventInfo::send+00000093
    [ 36] 0x000000000531c705    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+01820421 hgWaitforbuttonpress+00003589
    [ 37] 0x00000000052d43b3    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+01524659 ResizeProxy::positionCallback+00000515
    [ 38] 0x00000000052d3ca8    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+01522856 ResizeProxy::FigureProxy_ResizeFcn+00000072
    [ 39] 0x0000000005356c44    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\hg.dll+02059332 FigureHandleHGPeerQueue+00007188
    [ 40] 0x0000000073d2eb45 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwgui.dll+00453445 wm_Resize_With_Rects_Fcn+00000229
    [ 41] 0x0000000075c73daf C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libuij.dll+00015791 UIJ_MarkEventFinished+00006607
    [ 42] 0x0000000075c974ac C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libuij.dll+00160940 uij::JavaDraw2D::paintQuadStrip+00001500
    [ 43] 0x0000000074f7ae38   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd.dll+00241208 uddSetListenerRecursionWarning+00000680
    [ 44] 0x0000000074f7b48c   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd.dll+00242828 UDListenerManagerHost::notifyEvent+00000076
    [ 45] 0x0000000074f738dd   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd.dll+00211165 UDEventInfo::send+00000093
    [ 46] 0x0000000005c07ddb C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\udd_mi.dll+00032219 MErrorException::operator=+00028011
    [ 47] 0x0000000005d6f9d6   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00391638 UIW_IsUserMessage+00000086
    [ 48] 0x0000000005d70095   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00393365 UIW_SetGLIMUserMsg+00000117
    [ 49] 0x00000000779387fe                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00165886 GetMenuBarInfo+00000638
    [ 50] 0x000000007791f5fb                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00062971 SystemParametersInfoW+00000235
    [ 51] 0x0000000077924895                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00084117 IsProcessDPIAware+00000465
    [ 52] 0x0000000077a611f5                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00332277 KiUserCallbackDispatcher+00000031
    [ 53] 0x0000000077929e6a                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00106090 SfmDxSetSwapChainStats+00000026
    [ 54] 0x000000007792615e                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00090462 GetMessageA+00000078
    [ 55] 0x0000000005d4a074   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00237684 win_sleep+00000868
    [ 56] 0x0000000079fb5529 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00021801 ioCmdLineEditSave+00001065
    [ 57] 0x0000000079fb82ee C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00033518 ioCmdLineEditSave+00012782
    [ 58] 0x0000000079fb8676 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00034422 ioReadLine+00000118
    [ 59] 0x0000000079fb870e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00034574 ioReadLine+00000270
    [ 60] 0x0000000079fbc669 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00050793 mnInitializeParser+00001609
    [ 61] 0x0000000079fbc725 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00050981 mnInitializeParser+00001797
    [ 62] 0x0000000079fbcee6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00052966 mnParser+00000454
    [ 63] 0x000000007499daa4   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00187044 mcrInstance::mnParser_on_interpreter_thread+00000036
    [ 64] 0x0000000074982220   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00074272 mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00031664
    [ 65] 0x0000000074982280   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00074368 mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00031760
    [ 66] 0x0000000005d6f9d6   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00391638 UIW_IsUserMessage+00000086
    [ 67] 0x0000000005d70095   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00393365 UIW_SetGLIMUserMsg+00000117
    [ 68] 0x00000000779387fe                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00165886 GetMenuBarInfo+00000638
    [ 69] 0x000000007791f5fb                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00062971 SystemParametersInfoW+00000235
    [ 70] 0x0000000077924895                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00084117 IsProcessDPIAware+00000465
    [ 71] 0x0000000077a611f5                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00332277 KiUserCallbackDispatcher+00000031
    [ 72] 0x000000007792908a                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00102538 PeekMessageW+00000186
    [ 73] 0x00000000779250fe                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00086270 GetKeyState+00000238
    [ 74] 0x0000000077923a6f                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00080495 PeekMessageA+00000087
    [ 75] 0x0000000005d49a1b   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00236059 UIW_SetCurrentDialog+00000731
    [ 76] 0x0000000005d71532   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00398642 ws_FreeSystemFont+00000482
    [ 77] 0x0000000004388930 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00887088 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00055600
    [ 78] 0x00000000043892f5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00889589 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00058101
    [ 79] 0x000000000438a100 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00893184 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00061696
    [ 80] 0x00000000043928d2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00927954 svWS_ProcessPendingEvents+00001090
    [ 81] 0x000000007498329d   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00078493 mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00035885
    [ 82] 0x0000000074983562   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00079202 mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00036594
    [ 83] 0x0000000074976915   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00026901 mcrInstantiationError::operator=+00003781
    [ 84] 0x0000000074979d52   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00040274 mcr_invoke_on_interpreter_thread+00001602
    [ 85] 0x0000000140005591 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00021905
    [ 86] 0x0000000140005c3a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00023610
    [ 87] 0x0000000140006103 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00024835
    [ 88] 0x00000000778059ed                   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll+00088557 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000013
    [ 89] 0x0000000077a3c541                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00181569 RtlUserThreadStart+00000033


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: What do you see when you click details? Could it be something you're doing that's causing a memory violation of some sort?

Comment: what method do you use to maximize the GUI ? (programmatic or just clicking on the window "maximise" button)

Comment: @Hoki I just click on the window "maximise" button. Not doing it programatically.

Comment: @RyanJ I have edited the question. I do not understand what you meant by memory violation. Maybe you could explain it in simpler terms.

Comment: @BlackDagger Memory violation means that a program or function is attempting to write to memory that is not valid. A segmentation violation is what you're seeing, which in the programming world usually means a null or uninitialized pointer is being referenced in a function. The stack trace you posted shows that it's happening in the `getNumStrings` function of the `libmwgui.dll` file. This is Mathworks provided functionality, so this might be an issue for their support team. Have you tried contacting them?